# Outlook - Easier way to address message to contact?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Is there a quicker way to message an e-mail to someone in my address book when I have outlook 2007 connected to an exchange server?  By default it goes to the GAL when I am selecting names, then I have to select All contacts...

These people are frequently not in in my autocomplete (NK2 file), by the way.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried typing the first few characters of the recipients name and hitting ALT-K?